# Почему flexbox требует установки элемента в column?

Tags: html, css

Не могу разобраться, почему в шапке приходится выставлять элемент в `column`, а не в `row`, чтобы два новых блока в шапке располагались горизонтально.

Ведь по идее ничего не наследуется.
Вот сам код: https://jsfiddle.net/4ub00gt7/
Вопрос про 24 строку. По идее же `row` должен быть. column у нас же вертикально, а row горизонтально идет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главная ось уже переопределена выше в классе `.Container`, поэтому дочерние элементы выстраиваются по вертикали, т.е. ряды уже стали не горизонтально, а вертикально. Если указать для `.Myheader` `flex-direction: row;`, но ряды в нашем случае это же колонки, поэтому чтобы снова изменить направление пишем `flex-direction: column;`, чтобы колонки снова стали рядами.

Comment: Вы либо не понятно написали, либо что-то наврали. Не нужно никакой column выставлять, если автору нужно расположение слева направо внутри шапки

Comment: Абсолютно верно. В примере автора переопределение осей в блоке `.Myheader` не нужно и display:flex; нужно просто убать. Но вопрос был задан, поэтому был дан ответ.

Comment: Ось всегда по дефолту горизонтальная вне зависимости от родителей. И ничего не наследуется. Может все же вы пишете что-то не то?

Comment: flex-direction - направление главной оси по которой выстраиваются дочерние элементы (по умолчанию row - по горизонтали слева направо)
flex-direction: column; -- главная ось по вертикали сверху вниз, элементы соответственно выстраиваются также сверху вниз, а не слева направо.

Comment: Это мне известно